# Nginx php-fpm subdirectory

Tags: nginx, php

I want to run php-fpm via nginx, but for different locations I want to specify different roots:

for path:

`http://localhost/ -> /usr/share/nginx/html
http://localhost/pma -> /var/www/default/phpMyAdmin/
http://localhost/pga -> /var/www/default/phpPgAdmin/`

My configuration doesn't work properly:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    try_files $uri =404;
    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /40x.html
    #
    error_page  404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }

    location /pma {
        root /var/www/default/phpMyAdmin;
        try_files $uri =404;
        index index.html index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {             
        try_files $uri =404;
        include        fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

I always receive 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `location /pma` and `root /var/www/default/phpMyAdmin` request `http://server/pma/index.php` was search file `/var/www/default/phpMyAdmin/pma/index.php`.
Use something like this:

```
location /pma/ {
  rewrite /pma/ /phpMyAdmin/ last;
}
location /phpMyAdmin {
  root /var/www/default/
  try_files $uri =404;
  index index.html index.php;
}
```

or rename /var/www/default/phpMyAdmin to /var/www/default/pma and change config to

```
location /pma {
  root /var/www/default/
  try_files $uri =404;
  index index.html index.php;
}
```

Comment: I have still 404 both on `/pma` and `/phpMyAdmin` url (index file is ignored? but this is error 404 not 403), and `/pma/index.php` and `/phpMyAdmin/index.php` is message from fpm: `No input file specified.` (files permission are set properly for `nginx.nginx` and whole path has read flag. Static files works perfectly.

Comment: Ok I have solved this problem by adding `$uri/` (with trailing slash) to `try_files`. So finally: `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;`

Answer (score 1):

Here is code that i'm using in nginx.

```
location /phpMyAdmin {
root /var/www/default;
index index.php index.html;
location ~ .php$ {
                  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                  fastcgi_index index.php;
                  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/default$fastcgi_script_name;
                  include fastcgi_params;
                }
}
```

Comment: When I enter `/phpMyAdmin` path, 404 error is displayed. When I enter `/phpMyAdmin/index.php` everything is ok. Why `root` directive and `fastcgi_index` are ignored?

Comment: And `rewrite /pma/ /phpMyAdmin/ last;` doesn't work.

Comment: Ok I have solved this problem by adding `$uri/` (with trailing slash) to `try_files`. So finally: `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;`

Comment: No. Location `/pma` is not mapped to `/phpMyAdmin`, while `rewrite /pma/ /phpMyAdmin/ last;`.

Comment: No. I need mapping :)

Comment: Try using this rewrite ^/pma/$ /phpMyAdmin/ last;